# Javascript code to enable a checkbox on the click event of other checkbox

Tags: javascript

I want to enable a checkbox on the click event of the other check box.
Means the checkbox can be modified only when the 1st checkbox is clicked

can i have some suggestions of the java script function

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1"),
    checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");

checkbox1.addEventListener("change", function() {
    checkbox2.disabled = !checkbox1.checked;
}, false);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fdRge/